# Is it possible to use libxml with unicode xmlchar?

Tags: c++, unicode, libxml2

Is it possible to use libxml with unicode?

For example the xmlParseDoc function takes an xmlChar

xmlChar has the following definition:

```
typedef unsigned char xmlChar;
```

I would like for libxml to interpret all as 2 byte chars.

I have a feeling that the following would not work properly with the lib:

```
typedef unsigned short xmlChar;
```

Note: I'm not talking about when it actually reads/writes the xml encoding. I know that supports unicode.  What I want is for the interface into the lib to be with unicode strings wstring instead of normal strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in a [link](http://xmlsoft.org/encoding.html) provided by @Mitch Wheat

You cannot re-define xmlchar to be an unsigned short.  However if you encode your strings as UTF-8 then xmlChar will properly handle unicode.

You can convert a string in windows to UTF8 via calling WideCharToMultiByte with a parameter of CP_UTF8